# Objective-C Library For Arithmetic String Coding

Tags: objective-c, machine-learning

I need to dynamically convert some relatively short strings (20 characters or less), into numeric values for use in a Support Vector Machine (SVM). The SVM I am using can only handle double values, so I was thinking it made sense to arithmetically encode and decode the short strings into double values.

Does my approach of using arithmetic coding make sense, and if so are there any objective-c libraries for performing such encoding?

I have been searching, and have only been able to find descriptions of coding algorithms.